# What compatibility changes required for Solr 1.4 and Solrj 4.6?

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I've upgraded Solrj from 1.4 to 4.6, and supporting both Solr server 1.4 and Solr server 4.

When I execute the following code with Solrj 4.6 and Solr server 1.4, I got an exception `Invalid version (expected 2, but 1) or the data in not in 'javabin' format`.

```
HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(baseURL);
try {
    System.out.println(server.ping());;
} catch (SolrServerException | IOException e1) {
}
```

In order to solve this cross-version compatibility, it is mentioned, in solr wiki , to set parser as XMLResponseParser. With this implementation, my code changed as below:

```
HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(baseURL);
server.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
try {
    System.out.println(server.ping());;
} catch (SolrServerException | IOException e1) {
}
```

Now I am getting different errors as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Expected content type application/xml; charset=UTF-8 but got text/xml;charset=UTF-8. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">3</int><lst name="params"><str name="fl">*</str><str name="echoParams">all</str><str name="version">2.2</str><str name="echoParams">all</str><str name="q">solrpingquery</str><str name="qt">standard</str><str name="wt">xml</str><str name="version">2.2</str></lst></lst><str name="status">OK</str>
</response>
```

I request your help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to JIRA (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5532) this bug was here in Solr 4.6

I will recommend you to update Solr 4.6 to 4.6.1 at least, or to 4.7 or even to latest 4.10, if it's possible for you.